# list of todos (todonotes) is empty with llncs

Tags: todonotes, lncs

I am using `todonotes` together with Springer's `llncs` and I noticed that the list of todos created with `\listoftodos` remains empty, regardless how often I run `pdflatex`. With other document classes its working fine.

Example:

```
%\documentclass{scrartcl} %list of todos is correct
\documentclass{llncs} %list of todos is empty
\usepackage{todonotes}

\begin{document}

\listoftodos

\section{Contents}
test text \todo{test}

\end{document}
```

Is there an easy workaround?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `llncs` class sets

```
\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}
```

so the `todo` items, which are declared as level 1 don't appear:

```
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\listoftodos
```

will show the items.