# Why do I see this weird behavior when using the acmart class and the todonotes package?

Tags: todonotes, acmart

The following (not quite) MWE

```
\documentclass{acmart}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\begin{document}
\title{ACM Class and the todonotes package}
\author{Author}
\maketitle
\todo{A todo.}
\listoftodos
\end{document}
```

yields the following error:

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \@@par 
l.9 \end
        {document}
```

while the following code

```
\documentclass{acmart}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\begin{document}
\title{ACM Class and the todonotes package}
\author{Author}
\maketitle
\todo{A todo.}
\listoftodos\\
\end{document}
```

compiles nicely (using TeX Live 2017).

With the `article` class I don't have to add a line break `\\` or, more generally, a `{}` after `\listoftodos` as a workaround. It seems there is an incompatibility? Can this be seen as a bug in either the `acmart` class or the `todonotes` package? Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

acmart somewhat bravely redefines the internal `\@starttoc` command to take two arguments rather than one, the second one being some kind of subheading in the list. You can put that text (or just `{}`) after `\listof...`

```
\documentclass{acmart}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\begin{document}
\title{ACM Class and the todonotes package}
\author{Author}
\maketitle
\todo{A todo.}


\listoftodos{list of todos}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Reminds me of `amsart`…

Comment: @egreg so it is, the code is almost identical.

Comment: @davidcarlisle and egreg It turns out that listoftodos is not working at all (and without error!) in my second MWE.

Comment: @Mario I don't have llncs and that edit seems to be a completely different question and should be asked as a new question, unless llncs uses the same definition of `\@starttoc` in which case your llncs example should be `\listoftodos{}` not `\\listoftodos`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You're right, I undid the edit. FYI, the incompatibility of todonotes and llncs has been around for a while but is solved with https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103735/list-of-todos-todonotes-is-empty-with-llncs

Comment: @Mario oh that egreg bloke and the answer worked? amazing:-)