# List of todos (todonotes) is empty with acl2020

Tags: todonotes

The `todonotes` list of todos appears empty when using the `acl2020` style package (available [here](http://acl2020.org/downloads/acl2020-templates.zip)).

Here's a working example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article} %list of todos is empty
\usepackage[hyperref]{acl2020}
\usepackage{todonotes}

\begin{document}

\listoftodos

\section{Contents}
test text \todo{test}

\end{document}
```

There's a [similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103735/list-of-todos-todonotes-is-empty-with-llncs) with the `llncs` document style, however the fix, `\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}` doesn't help.

Comment: Not at a pc, but have you tried loading todonotes before acl2020 (personally I tend to use the fixme package instead as, with the right configuration, it can be used in more places than to do)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ACL style contains the following:

```
% We're never going to need a table of contents, so just flush it to
% save space --- suggested by drstrip@sandia-2
\def\addcontentsline#1#2#3{}
```

You can edit the style to only flush the TOC lines for the final copy:

```
% We're never going to need a table of contents, so just flush it to
% save space --- suggested by drstrip@sandia-2
\ifacl@finalcopy
\def\addcontentsline#1#2#3{}
\fi
```